# Why YearMonth is Temporal while MonthDay is not Temporal?

Tags: java, java-time

Why `YearMonth` class is *Temporal* (interface) while `MonthDay` is not Temporal?

This seems strange, because both classes are almost identical in their meaning.

I may suggest that MonthDay is never used anywhere where Temporal interface is used, but maybe there is a better reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a question of reading the documentation of `MonthDay`, with thanks to davidxxx and others for finding the right quote:

> This class implements `TemporalAccessor` rather than `Temporal`. This is
>   because it is not possible to define whether February 29th is valid or
>   not without external information, preventing the implementation of
>   plus/minus. Related to this, `MonthDay` only provides access to query
>   and set the fields `MONTH_OF_YEAR` and `DAY_OF_MONTH`.

You may read this in conjunction with this snippet from the documentation of `Temporal`:

> This is the base interface type for date, time and offset objects that
>   are complete enough to be manipulated using plus and minus.

They have not wanted to define plus and minus for `MonthDay`. Because for example it’s not clear what February 28 plus 1 day is. In some years it is February 29, in other years it’s March 1.

In comparison, adding a month or a year to a `YearMonth` always gives a well-defined and not surprising result.

**Links**

- [Documentation of `Temporal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html)
- [Documentation of `MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html)

Comment: That doesn't appear explicitly in the documentation but yet your guess sounds very right/

Comment: @davidxxx It does say for `MonthDay`: "While the combination is contiguous, from days to months within years, the combination does not have sufficient information to define the valid range of values for day-of-month.".

Comment: @daniu Indeed, I relied only on the quote of the documentation that finally was not exhaustive on this point. And this also stated in `MonthDay` with more details. I updated with it.